# Можно ли работать с SQL без транзакций?

Tags: sql, transaction

Мне недавно "старший по званию" задал вопрос, как в заголовке.

Мы всегда можем обернуть запрос в begin transaction/commit/rollback, но является ли транзакцией выполнение запроса, когда мы не оборачиваем его в транзакцию явно?
Происходит ли неявное формирование транзакции?

Comment: Зависит от СУБД. Можно быть SQL и не быть транзакционной базой вовсе, `myisam` в `mysql`, например.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Автоматическое принятие транзакций:**
Каждая отдельная инструкция является транзакцией.

**Явные транзакции:**
Каждая транзакция явно начинается с инструкции BEGIN TRANSACTION и явно заканчивается инструкцией COMMIT или ROLLBACK.

**Неявные транзакции:**
Новая транзакция неявно начинается, когда предыдущая транзакция завершена, но каждая транзакция явно завершается инструкцией COMMIT или ROLLBACK.

Answer (score 1):

Да, тогда, по умолчанию, каждый запрос - отдельная транзакция.